# Empty objects insertion in context by attaching inside a delegate

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, delegates

I am using Entity Framework 6.1 in `C#`. I create a context in a function and I invoke a delegate using a generic argument and passing the context as another:

```
public void Save<NativeType>(Item item,
                             Func<NativeType, DatabaseMappingContext, bool> saveDel)
{
  using(var db = new DatabaseMappingContext())
  {
    saveDel(item, db);
    DbSet<NativeType> dbSet = db.DbSets[nativeType].Cast<NativeType>();
    dbSet.Add(item);
    db.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

And inside the delegate:

```
(Item item, DatabaseMappingContext db) =>
{
  db.InnerItems.Attach(item.InnerItem);
  return true;
}
```

The issue that I face is that inside `db.InnerItems` context there are empty `InnerItem` objects inserted after the `Attach()` invocation. I am thinking that it has to do something with using generics in combination with delegates and the context lifetime, I am not sure though. Any ideas on this? Am I doing something wrong?